# WKWebView change User Agent for specific URLs only

Tags: wkwebview

I have a certain website I am integrating into my app via a WKWebView and for some subrequests (specifically, `<img src>`) I **have** to provide a specific user agent as otherwise they don't return image data. On the other hand, that same user agent would cause the HTML/JS to not render correctly.

That quirky behaviour is outside of my control.

I am looking for ways to inject something into WKWebView that would allow me to replace my `User-Agent` based on the path of the URL.

I can't use private APIs as the App is published on App Store.